# Alignment problem in Beamer

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

While using the code below my equation goes out of the page. I want to make the equation into two lines to fit but I'm unable to do. Please help me out.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{2}{6}\selectfont}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{rules}{Rule}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{}
\title{Negative Dimensional Integral and Modified Method of Brackets}
\author[Sumit Banik]{\textbf {Work By-Sumit Banik\\ \footnotesize Supervised by: B Ananthanarayan}}
\institute{Indian Institute of Science\\Bangalore- 560012}
\date{}
\begin {document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Negative Dimensional Integral Method}
\begin{itemize}
\item Using the above equation \eqref{3} and Gauss Summation Theorem for terminating hyper-geometric series  we get:
\begin{equation}
I(r,s)=\displaystyle{\pi^{d/2}(p^2)^{r+s+d/2}
\frac{\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(s+1)\Gamma(1-r-s-d/2}{\Gamma(1+r+s+d/2)\Gamma(1-s-d/2)\Gamma(1-r-d/2)}}
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to move the prefactor in the fraction and to drop the equation number. Equation numbers in beamer should generally be avoided.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{2}{6}\selectfont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{}
\begin {document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Negative Dimensional Integral Method}
Using the above equation and Gauss Summation Theorem for terminating hyper-geometric series  we get:
\[
I(r,s)=
\frac{\pi^{d/2}(p^2)^{r+s+d/2}\Gamma(r+1)\Gamma(s+1)\Gamma(1-r-s-d/2}{\Gamma(1+r+s+d/2)\Gamma(1-s-d/2)\Gamma(1-r-d/2)}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]